# Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180. Got this problem when deploying old react project to vercel

Tags: reactjs, github, build, vercel

```
Error: Failed to launch chrome!
[1217/173320.655428:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.

TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

at onClose (/vercel/path0/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:348:14)
at Interface.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:337:50)
at Interface.emit (node:events:529:35)
at Interface.close (node:internal/readline/interface:534:10)
at Socket.onend (node:internal/readline/interface:260:10)
at Socket.emit (node:events:529:35)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1368:12)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Hi there, I've faced this problem when I was trying to deploy my old react project on vercel via GitHub which was built with Create-React-App in Dec 2022.